# Why doesn't wrapping elements in divs induvidually and styling them work?

Tags: html, css

I've tried taking out the main class, renaming things, using other editors, putting other elements in the div(s), even changing indentations, and googling to no avail. I feel like I'm missing out on a fundamental concept of how divs work in CSS, so I would really appreciate some help. Thank you!

```css
.main {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
}

.inputbox {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="image"> 
      <img src="google.png"/>
  </div>

  <div class="inputbox">
      <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a runnable snippet. Seems like all those CSS is getting applied as expected. Please explain your issue in more details.

Comment: you are not writing what you expect as a result

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A div is a container. It's like a box. It contains the other elements. You can have a div within a div.

If I understand your issue correctly, you're assigning the classes to the wrong divs and elements.

I wrote this code, I used some styles just to simplify what is going on instead of using classes.

I also added some styles to make it look better and to give some examples of what I am referring to.

I believe this will give you a general idea of what is going on.

To make things easier, use chrome and right-click the screen, and click inspect. There you can modify the styles on the fly and find out which element you need to style to get the desired effect.

```css
.main {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

.inputbox {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="image" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <img src="https://www.tech-butlers.com/techbutlers.gif" style="width:300px;" />
  </div>

  <div class="inputbox" style="margin: 33px auto;">
    <input type="text" style="width: 500px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```